# Parsing xml with php and xpath

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm trying to parse an xml file to return a item with a specific id only, but having trouble
making it work.

here's what I have in php

```
$xml_str = file_get_contents("test.xml");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_str);
$albid = $_GET['id'];

$nodes = $xml->xpath('//library/book[@id=1]');

foreach($nodes as $node) {
echo $node['title'].'<br/>';
}
```

First, the php is not returning anything from the xml file.

What would I need to fix to return the data?

Also, how would I enter $albid into the xpath so that the id will be retrieved from the link?

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks!

--and here's the sample xml file--

```
<library>
<book id="1">
    <title>PHP and MySQL</title>
    <author fname="miguel" lname="alvarez">Miguel Alvarez</author>
</book>
<book id="2">
    <title>JAVA 123</title>
    <author fname="william" lname="vega">WIlliam Vega</author>
</book>
```

Comment: Don't forget your closing </library> tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you must close the `<library>` tag, otherwise the XML is malformed and parsing will fail.

SimpleXMLElement::xpath() returns an object ([ref](http://lv.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php)), so inside the loop do: `echo $node->title.'<br/>';`

Getting $albid into string.. well, use string concatenation: `$nodes = $xml->xpath('//library/book[@id='.$albid.']');`

Comment: Thanks so much for explaining how/why to change the code.
Works great!

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$xml_str = file_get_contents("test.xml");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_str);
$albid = $_GET['id'];

$nodes = $xml->xpath("//library/book[@id=$albid]");

foreach($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node->title.'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: funny how it's always a small piece of code that does the trick.
I got it to work from above, but thanks for the alternative way using xpath